# Scikit-Learn: How to use Transformation of Matrix X to transform Target Variables Y

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, normalization

I'm working on a regression problem, with my features in a matrix X and target values in Y.

I want to scale the input. I'm doing it using `sklearn`'s `MinMaxScaler`:

```
# scale data to 0-1
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)
```

My understanding is that the true labels vector `Y` should now be scaled accordingly. How do I do this using the `scaler` object? From the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html), I can pass the true labels to the fit_transform method, but it seems like this is only for "pipeline compatibility" - i.e, the method disregards `Y` and only returns the transformed X.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't scale target variable `Y` with that *scaler*.

Because *[MinMaxScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html)*:

> Transforms features by scaling each feature to a given range.

It doesn't transform target variable. Or more precisely since you've fitted it on features, then you can only apply it on features.

The case when you will need the scaler again is when you try to apply the model to your testing data to *make predictions*, you need to use the same scaler to transform the features of your testing data as well so the result will be consistent.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this I understand, I guess what I should've mentioned is that I'm doing time series prediction, so my target variable is a "feature" just like the features in the matrix X. Then the best practice in this case would be to apply the scaling before I divide into X,y? It's what I initially tried but it's a bit cumbersome so I thought there must be a scalar that can be applied on a 1D array after fitted on a 2D array...

Comment: If you need to scale *y*, you'll have to make another scaler. Let's call it `scaler_target`. Scale `X` and `y` separately, as later on you'll probably need them again on the testing data set. So the scaler fitted from features should be applied to features, and the scaler_target fitted from target variable should be applied to the target variable. Hope this is clear.

Comment: it's a little against my intuition to scale them seperately but I'll go for that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays an option is to use the [TransformedTargetRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor.html) meta-estimator to apply a transformation to the target variable.